# How to send the results of assertEquals to another method

Tags: testng

I have a method that has set of assertEquals

```
@Test(enabled=true,groups = {"regression","sanity"})
public void Samplecode()
{
Constants.driver.get(Constants.INVENTORY_SUMMARY_URL);
Assert.assertEquals(invsummpagedetails.getTechnology().getText(), "Test1");
Assert.assertEquals(invsummpagedetails.getSoftware().getText(), "Test2");
Assert.assertEquals(invsummpagedetails.getChassis().getText(), "Test3");
}
```

I want to send the result this method to another method in different package.

I want this to update my test case result as PASSED or FAILED automatically in the repository where we store our test cases

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter` and override methods `onTestFailure`, `onTestSuccess`, etc. here you get test result and you can pass it to your 'result processor'.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated you have to override methods for `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter`

This listener catches the result of your test case. My guess is that you want to track the results of your test cases. Am I correct? If so i can show a complete webinterface with database structure to show you a good overview of your test runs.

But for how to implement this in your test framework you have do to the following.

Are you running your testcases with maven or eclipse?

Eclipse:

All testcase need this annotation

```
@Test(testListener=TestListener.class)
```

Maven:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <listeners>
                        <listener class-name="TestListener" />
                    </listeners>                       
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then implement TestListener

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

  public TestListener(){        
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
    super.onTestSuccess(tr);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {    
    super.onTestFailure(tr);    
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
    super.onTestSkipped(tr);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext testContext) {
    super.onStart(testContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext testContext) {
    super.onFinish(testContext);
  }
}
```